# How to diagnose and fix TaskCanceledException when connecting to remote database?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I connected to the database which is on a remote hosting machine.

This is the code that throws the exception:

```
private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)   
{           
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Drugs"].ConnectionString;
    sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

    await sqlConnection.OpenAsync(); // throws System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException  
}
```

Here is my app.config file:

```
<connectionStrings>  
    <add name="Drugs"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
    connectionString="Data Source=<ip address>;Initial Catalog=<database>;User Id=<my username>;Password=<my password>" />
</connectionStrings>
```

How can I diagnose and fix this?

Comment: It's possibly behind a firewall, which would be normal for a hosted server.  Is it your own server?  Can you open a port on the firewall?

Comment: Also, you've tagged the question as using MySql, but your code is for connecting to SqlServer.

Comment: Yes,thank you, i understand my mistake

Comment: chnage "await sqlConnection.OpenAsync();" to "sqlConnection.Open();" - now what's the error?

Comment: looks like you've abandoned your question?  Without further information, it's unlikely you'll get an answer that helps you.

Comment: My mistake was:    1)I want connected to Mysql db,although i used sqlconnection 2)HERE:<connectionStrings>  
    <add name="Drugs"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
    connectionString="Data Source=<ip address>;Initial Catalog=<database>;User Id=<my username>;Password=<my password>" />
</connectionStrings> I should use another type of connection